# How To Get Value Of Canvas From A Wheel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

How To Get The Value Of A Canvas . I have wheel which is rotating on mouse over the wheel stops now i want to echo out the value on which it was stopped. It is printing the whole array . Not the one on which the wheel stop.

```
$("#canvas").mouseover(function(){
  backup= ctx;
  alert(myData);
  ctx = null;
});
```

this is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/z61n9ccx/3/

Here is the full code:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw = canvas.width;
var ch = canvas.height;


var PI2 = Math.PI * 2;
var myData = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12];
var cx = 150;
var cy = 150;
var radius = 150;

var wheel = document.createElement('canvas');
var wheelCtx = wheel.getContext('2d');

var indicator = document.createElement('canvas');
var indicatorCtx = indicator.getContext('2d');


var angle = PI2 - PI2 / 4;

var myColor = [];
for (var i = 0; i < myData.length; i++) {
  myColor.push(randomColor());
}

makeWheel();
makeIndicator();

requestAnimationFrame(animate);

function makeWheel() {

  wheel.width = wheel.height = radius * 2 + 2;
  wheelCtx.lineWidth = 1;
  wheelCtx.font = '40px Pacifico, cursive';
  wheelCtx.textAlign = 'center';
  wheelCtx.textBaseline = 'middle';

  var cx = wheel.width / 2;
  var cy = wheel.height / 2;

  var sweepAngle = PI2 / myData.length;
  var startAngle = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < myData.length; i++) {

    // calc ending angle based on starting angle
    var endAngle = startAngle + sweepAngle;

    // draw the wedge
    wheelCtx.beginPath();
    wheelCtx.moveTo(cx, cy);
    wheelCtx.arc(cx, cy, radius, startAngle, endAngle, false);
    wheelCtx.closePath();
    wheelCtx.fillStyle = myColor[i];
    wheelCtx.strokeStyle = 'black';
    wheelCtx.fill();
    wheelCtx.stroke();

    // draw the label
    var midAngle = startAngle + (endAngle - startAngle) / 2;
    var labelRadius = radius * .85;
    var x = cx + (labelRadius) * Math.cos(midAngle);
    var y = cy + (labelRadius) * Math.sin(midAngle);
    wheelCtx.fillStyle = 'gold';
    wheelCtx.fillText(myData[i], x, y);
    wheelCtx.strokeText(myData[i], x, y);

    // increment angle
    startAngle += sweepAngle;
  }


}

function makeIndicator() {
  indicator.width = indicator.height = radius + radius / 10;
  indicatorCtx.font = '40px Georgia';
  indicatorCtx.textAlign = 'center';
  indicatorCtx.textBaseline = 'middle';
  indicatorCtx.fillStyle = 'skyblue';
  indicatorCtx.strokeStyle = 'blue';
  indicatorCtx.lineWidth = 1;

  var cx = indicator.width / 2;
  var cy = indicator.height / 2;

  indicatorCtx.beginPath();
  indicatorCtx.moveTo(cx - radius / 8, cy);
  indicatorCtx.lineTo(cx, cy - indicator.height / 2);
  indicatorCtx.lineTo(cx + radius / 8, cy);
  indicatorCtx.closePath();
  indicatorCtx.fillStyle = 'skyblue'
  indicatorCtx.fill();
  indicatorCtx.stroke();

  indicatorCtx.beginPath();
  indicatorCtx.arc(cx, cy, radius / 3, 0, PI2);
  indicatorCtx.closePath();
  indicatorCtx.fill();
  indicatorCtx.stroke();

  indicatorCtx.fillStyle = 'blue';
  indicatorCtx.fillText('Prizes', cx, cy);
}



function animate(time) {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cw, ch);
  ctx.translate(cw / 2, ch / 2);
  ctx.rotate(angle);
  ctx.drawImage(wheel, -wheel.width / 2, -wheel.height / 2);
  ctx.rotate(-angle);
  ctx.translate(-cw / 2, -ch / 2);
  ctx.drawImage(indicator, cw / 2 - indicator.width / 2, ch / 2 - indicator.height / 2)
  angle += PI2 / 360;
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}


function randomColor() {
  return ('#' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16));
}
var backup = null;
$("#canvas").mouseover(function() {
  backup = ctx;
  alert(myData);
  ctx = null;
});
$("#canvas").mouseout(function() {
  // backup= ctx;
  ctx = backup;
  animate();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="600" style="background-color:#ffff">
</canvas>
```

Comment: How is `ctx` defined? Is this a global? What is `myData`?

Comment: ctx is global and myData is defined in the function makewheel()

Comment: `myData` would be out of scope then and not be available to this function. Your fiddle seems to workm so let me look over that a bit.

Comment: it is printing the whole array not the on on which the wheel stops

Comment: Each of your wedges has an original starting & ending angle. When the wheel is spun the spinning causes those starting & ending angles to be rotated. To track where the wheel ends up you test each starting+spunAngle & ending+spunAngle against the  indicator's angle. The chosen wedge will be `starting+spunAngle <= indicatorAngle <= endingAngle+spunAngle`. Note that since the wheel will probably spin >360 degrees you will need to normalize all angles between 0 & 360 (360 degrees ==  2*PI radians).

Comment: **For example**, wedge#1 originally starts at 0 degrees & ends at 360/12wedges*1 == 30 degrees. The indicator is at 270 degrees. So if the wheel spins 250 degrees the test for wedge#1 winning is: `0+250 < 270 < 30+250`. Since this test is true, wedge#1 wins. **Another example**, wedge#2 originally starts at 360/12*1 == 30 & ends at 360/12wedges*2 == 60. The indicator is at 270 degrees. So if the wheel spins 250 degrees the test for wedge#2 winning is: `30+250 <= 270 <= 60+250`. Since this test is false, wedge#2 does not win.

Comment: I see the `myData` defined up front, yet I see no functions that update it. So it's it's passing the whole array to `alert()`. This is why you get the whole data.

Comment: yes i am looking for the solution.... working for two days

Comment: What function do you have to detect which wedge the indicator is over?

Comment: on mouse over the indicators stops so I just want to echo the number on which the indicators stops.

Comment: I get that, what do you have to determine which wedge the indicator is over when the animation stops? This is what @markE was trying to discuss with you.

Comment: @markE tried to make understand but for my poor english i am not been able to understand.

Comment: Maybe, if you determine the number of frames that it takes for a number to pass over a wedge. You could then start at 12, and decrement that by one when enough frames are passed. I would make this a global variable or an index that can then be called on your array: 11, 10, 9, ... 2, 1, 0.

Comment: @Twisty Can we make it more simpler . If I will click on the number it will echo the value of that number only

Comment: I'm still new to animations and canvas myself. In my mind, when the click event happens, you would need to check the Mouse's X, Y, and determine if they are within the border of the wedge drawing itself. I'm not very familiar with how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added a counter, and then use that as a index: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/L6nws9yz/2/

**HTML**

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="310" height="310" style="background-color:#ffff">
</canvas>
<div id="counterBox">
  <label>Counter:</label>
  <span></span>
</div>
<div id="countBox">
  <label>Index:</label>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw = canvas.width;
var ch = canvas.height;

var PI2 = Math.PI * 2;
var myData = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12];
var cx = 150;
var cy = 150;
var radius = 150;

var wheel = document.createElement('canvas');
var wheelCtx = wheel.getContext('2d');

var indicator = document.createElement('canvas');
var indicatorCtx = indicator.getContext('2d');
var currentSelection = 12;
var counter = 360;

var angle = PI2 - PI2 / 4;

var myColor = [];
for (var i = 0; i < myData.length; i++) {
  myColor.push(randomColor());
}

makeWheel();
makeIndicator();

requestAnimationFrame(animate);

function makeWheel() {

  wheel.width = wheel.height = radius * 2 + 2;
  wheelCtx.lineWidth = 1;
  wheelCtx.font = '40px Pacifico, cursive';
  wheelCtx.textAlign = 'center';
  wheelCtx.textBaseline = 'middle';

  var cx = wheel.width / 2;
  var cy = wheel.height / 2;

  var sweepAngle = PI2 / myData.length;
  var startAngle = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < myData.length; i++) {

    // calc ending angle based on starting angle
    var endAngle = startAngle + sweepAngle;

    // draw the wedge
    wheelCtx.beginPath();
    wheelCtx.moveTo(cx, cy);
    wheelCtx.arc(cx, cy, radius, startAngle, endAngle, false);
    wheelCtx.closePath();
    wheelCtx.fillStyle = myColor[i];
    wheelCtx.strokeStyle = 'black';
    wheelCtx.fill();
    wheelCtx.stroke();

    // draw the label
    var midAngle = startAngle + (endAngle - startAngle) / 2;
    var labelRadius = radius * .85;
    var x = cx + (labelRadius) * Math.cos(midAngle);
    var y = cy + (labelRadius) * Math.sin(midAngle);
    wheelCtx.fillStyle = 'gold';
    wheelCtx.fillText(myData[i], x, y);
    wheelCtx.strokeText(myData[i], x, y);

    // increment angle
    startAngle += sweepAngle;
  }


}

function makeIndicator() {
  indicator.width = indicator.height = radius + radius / 10;
  indicatorCtx.font = '40px Georgia';
  indicatorCtx.textAlign = 'center';
  indicatorCtx.textBaseline = 'middle';
  indicatorCtx.fillStyle = 'skyblue';
  indicatorCtx.strokeStyle = 'blue';
  indicatorCtx.lineWidth = 1;

  var cx = indicator.width / 2;
  var cy = indicator.height / 2;

  indicatorCtx.beginPath();
  indicatorCtx.moveTo(cx - radius / 8, cy);
  indicatorCtx.lineTo(cx, cy - indicator.height / 2);
  indicatorCtx.lineTo(cx + radius / 8, cy);
  indicatorCtx.closePath();
  indicatorCtx.fillStyle = 'skyblue'
  indicatorCtx.fill();
  indicatorCtx.stroke();

  indicatorCtx.beginPath();
  indicatorCtx.arc(cx, cy, radius / 3, 0, PI2);
  indicatorCtx.closePath();
  indicatorCtx.fill();
  indicatorCtx.stroke();

  indicatorCtx.fillStyle = 'blue';
  indicatorCtx.fillText('Prizes', cx, cy);
}


var lastloop = new Date;
var thisloop = new Date;
var fps = 0;

function animate(time) {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cw, ch);
  ctx.translate(cw / 2, ch / 2);
  ctx.rotate(angle);
  ctx.drawImage(wheel, -wheel.width / 2, -wheel.height / 2);
  ctx.rotate(-angle);
  ctx.translate(-cw / 2, -ch / 2);
  ctx.drawImage(indicator, cw / 2 - indicator.width / 2, ch / 2 - indicator.height / 2)
  angle += PI2 / 360;
  thisloop = new Date;
  fps = 1000 / (thisloop - lastloop);
  lastloop = thisloop;
  counter--;
  if (counter < 1) {
    counter = 360;
  }
  $("#counterBox span").html(counter);
  var index = counter / 30;
  $("#countBox span").html(Math.round(index));
  //$("#fpsBox span").html(fps);
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}


function randomColor() {
  return ('#' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16));
}

var backup = null;

$("#canvas").mouseover(function() {
  backup = ctx;
  alert(myData[Math.round(counter / 30)-1]);
  ctx = null;
});

$("#canvas").mouseout(function() {
  // backup= ctx;
  ctx = backup;
  animate();
});
```

Counter is set to 360 and then each frame decreases it. Take that and divide by 30 (360 / 12), and you can count each wedge. I round up and now I have 0 - 11 count.

**Update**

I moved the Index into a global space. To make it more precise, I used the `%` operator like so:

```
  counter--;
  if (counter == 0) {
    counter = 360;
  }
  $("#counterBox span").html(counter);
  if (counter % 30 === 0) {
    index--;
  }
  $("#countBox span").html(Math.round(index));
  if (index === 0) {
    index = 12;
  }
```

When you mouse over, you get the selection:

```
$("#canvas").mouseover(function() {
  backup = ctx;
  alert(index);
  ctx = null;
});
```

Comment: This will need some improvement. Looks like `.round()` is a bit aggressive, so when the counter is less than 15, resulting in a result less then 1/2 (0.5), it's going to round down and the index will be 0. Will see if I can get it to be more precise.

Comment: Nice solution. +1 for that.

Answer (score 1):

I wrapped everything in an [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) so that there aren't any global variables.

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/zhzb3mvL/)

It's important to note that the angle calculation is:

```
angle = degree * Math.PI / 180;
```

With that being said, you can calculate the current degree and normalize it using:

```
(angle * (180 / Math.PI)) % 360
```

I added a function called `getValue` which takes an `angle` parameter:

```
function getValue(angle) {
  var degree = (angle * (180 / Math.PI)) % 360,
      offsetIndex = (Math.floor(degree / sweepDegree) + offset) % myData.length,
      normalizedIndex = Math.abs(offsetIndex - (myData.length - 1));

  return myData[normalizedIndex];
}
```

It essentially calculates the current degree, normalizes it taking into account what the initial degree was when the animation was initialized (which is the offset). Then it divides the degree by the sweep degree, which is 30 in this case since there are 12 items (i.e., `360/12 === 30`) and rounds down.

```
var sweepDegree = 360 / myData.length;
var offset = (360 - (angle * (180 / Math.PI)) % 360) / sweepDegree;
```

This should work for a varying number of array items. In other words, nothing is hardcoded for a set length of 12 items (like in your case), so it should work for any given number of items.

Then you can simply use the `getValue` function in the `mouseover` event listener:

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/zhzb3mvL/)

```
$("#canvas").mouseover(function() {
  // ...
  alert(getValue(angle));
});
```

```js
(function() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  var cw = canvas.width;
  var ch = canvas.height;


  var PI2 = Math.PI * 2;
  var myData = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12];
  var cx = 150;
  var cy = 150;
  var radius = 150;

  var wheel = document.createElement('canvas');
  var wheelCtx = wheel.getContext('2d');

  var indicator = document.createElement('canvas');
  var indicatorCtx = indicator.getContext('2d');

  var angle = PI2 - PI2 / 4;
  var sweepDegree = 360 / myData.length;
  var offset = (360 - (angle * (180 / Math.PI)) % 360) / sweepDegree;

  var myColor = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < myData.length; i++) {
    myColor.push(randomColor());
  }

  makeWheel();
  makeIndicator();

  requestAnimationFrame(animate);

  function makeWheel() {

    wheel.width = wheel.height = radius * 2 + 2;
    wheelCtx.lineWidth = 1;
    wheelCtx.font = '40px Pacifico, cursive';
    wheelCtx.textAlign = 'center';
    wheelCtx.textBaseline = 'middle';

    var cx = wheel.width / 2;
    var cy = wheel.height / 2;

    var sweepAngle = PI2 / myData.length;
    var startAngle = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < myData.length; i++) {

      // calc ending angle based on starting angle
      var endAngle = startAngle + sweepAngle;

      // draw the wedge
      wheelCtx.beginPath();
      wheelCtx.moveTo(cx, cy);
      wheelCtx.arc(cx, cy, radius, startAngle, endAngle, false);
      wheelCtx.closePath();
      wheelCtx.fillStyle = myColor[i];
      wheelCtx.strokeStyle = 'black';
      wheelCtx.fill();
      wheelCtx.stroke();

      // draw the label
      var midAngle = startAngle + (endAngle - startAngle) / 2;
      var labelRadius = radius * .85;
      var x = cx + (labelRadius) * Math.cos(midAngle);
      var y = cy + (labelRadius) * Math.sin(midAngle);
      wheelCtx.fillStyle = 'gold';
      wheelCtx.fillText(myData[i], x, y);
      wheelCtx.strokeText(myData[i], x, y);

      // increment angle
      startAngle += sweepAngle;
    }


  }

  function makeIndicator() {
    indicator.width = indicator.height = radius + radius / 10;
    indicatorCtx.font = '40px Georgia';
    indicatorCtx.textAlign = 'center';
    indicatorCtx.textBaseline = 'middle';
    indicatorCtx.fillStyle = 'skyblue';
    indicatorCtx.strokeStyle = 'blue';
    indicatorCtx.lineWidth = 1;

    var cx = indicator.width / 2;
    var cy = indicator.height / 2;

    indicatorCtx.beginPath();
    indicatorCtx.moveTo(cx - radius / 8, cy);
    indicatorCtx.lineTo(cx, cy - indicator.height / 2);
    indicatorCtx.lineTo(cx + radius / 8, cy);
    indicatorCtx.closePath();
    indicatorCtx.fillStyle = 'skyblue'
    indicatorCtx.fill();
    indicatorCtx.stroke();

    indicatorCtx.beginPath();
    indicatorCtx.arc(cx, cy, radius / 3, 0, PI2);
    indicatorCtx.closePath();
    indicatorCtx.fill();
    indicatorCtx.stroke();

    indicatorCtx.fillStyle = 'blue';
    indicatorCtx.fillText('Prizes', cx, cy);
  }



  function animate(time) {
    if (ctx === null) {
      return
    }
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cw, ch);
    ctx.translate(cw / 2, ch / 2);
    ctx.rotate(angle);
    ctx.drawImage(wheel, -wheel.width / 2, -wheel.height / 2);
    ctx.rotate(-angle);
    ctx.translate(-cw / 2, -ch / 2);
    ctx.drawImage(indicator, cw / 2 - indicator.width / 2, ch / 2 - indicator.height / 2)
    angle += PI2 / 360;
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  }


  function randomColor() {
    return ('#' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16));
  }
  var backup = null;
  $("#canvas").mouseover(function() {
    backup = ctx;
    ctx = null;

    alert(getValue(angle));
  });
  $("#canvas").mouseout(function() {
    ctx = backup;
    animate();
  });

  function getValue(angle) {
    var degree = (angle * (180 / Math.PI)) % 360,
      offsetIndex = (Math.floor(degree / sweepDegree) + offset) % myData.length,
      normalizedIndex = Math.abs(offsetIndex - (myData.length - 1));

    return myData[normalizedIndex];
  }
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="600" style="background-color:#ffff">
</canvas>
```